Accessing shapes and textboxes in python-docx
This code can't seem to access text inside shapes, is there a way to do so?
from docx import Document

doc = Document('template.docx')
replace_word = {'Captain': 'Gerard B. Geronimo'}
for word in replace_word:
    for p in doc.paragraphs:
        if p.text.find(word) >= 0:
            p.text = p.text.replace(word, replace_word[word])

doc.save('note_demo.docx')

I tried everything that I could find on the internet but couldn't find anything.

Text in shapes and text boxes are not in paragraphs which directly are child-elements of document body. And Document.paragraphs only contain paragraphs which directly are child-elements of document body. Document.paragraphs not even contains paragraphs in table cells. Thus also for text in tables another approach would be needed.
But all text, also text in shapes and text boxes, is in CT_Text elements of the underlying document-body-XML-element. Thus XPath will be able to get all CT_Text elements (w:t) of CT_Body (w:body) using the path .//w:t. Having this elements, one can replace their text content.
Example:
from docx import Document

document = Document('template.docx')

replace_word = {'Captain': 'Gerard B. Geronimo'}

for word in replace_word:
    for textElement in document._body._element.xpath(".//w:t"):
        print(textElement.text)
        if textElement.text.find(word) >= 0:
            textElement.text = textElement.text.replace(word, replace_word[word])
        print(textElement.text)
            
document.save('result.docx')

This will work as long as the word searched is not split into multiple text runs and so multiple CT_Text elements. With a word like "Captain" this should not happen, as long as not parts of this word are formatted. But when the word contains spaces and/or special characters, this happens very fast. Microsoft Word is a beast if it comes to split text into different text runs for multiple reasons.
Your approach always searches and replaces the entire text content of the paragraphs. This probably loses formatting of some text runs but avoids the problem of not find text because it is split into multiple text runs. But that will not work for text in shapes and text boxes. My approach handles all text in all body elements, but only finds text which not is split into multiple text runs. Well, all good things never come together.

This second approach tries rebuilding your approach to consider text in shapes and text boxes. It considers all text in paragraphs no matter where they occur. And it searches and replaces the whole paragraph text no matter whether it is split into different text runs. It puts the whole replaced text in first text run. This probably loses formatting of some text runs. But that's the case with your approach too.
for word in replace_word:
    for paragraphElement in document._body._element.xpath(".//w:p"):
        print(paragraphElement.text)
        text = paragraphElement.text
        if text.find(word) >= 0:
            text = text.replace(word, replace_word[word])
            i = 0
            for ct_text in paragraphElement.xpath("./w:r/w:t | ./*/w:r/w:t"):
                ct_text.text = ""
                if (i == 0):
                    ct_text.text = text
                i += 1
        print(paragraphElement.text)

